# SEL_E_SECPKG_NOT_FOUND error from AcquireCredentialsHandle()

Tags: c++, windows, security, ssl

I get the above error when trying to run the code from Microsoft's Secure SOAP sample
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2ya483s.aspx

The call, from M'soft's code, seems to be correct:

```
Status = g_Sample_SecurityInit._SecurityFunc.AcquireCredentialsHandleA(
    NULL,                   // Name of principal    
    UNISP_NAME_A,           // Name of package
    SECPKG_CRED_OUTBOUND,   // Flags indicating use
    NULL,                   // Pointer to logon ID
    &m_SchannelCred,        // Package specific data
    NULL,                   // Pointer to GetKey() func
    NULL,                   // Value to pass to GetKey()
    &m_hClientCreds,        // (out) Cred Handle
    &tsExpiry);             // (out) Lifetime (optional)
```

Any ideas on how to proceed? FWIW, this is part of an SSL client, but I don't really need client side authentication.

Rony

Answer (score 1):

What OS are you running your client on?  This file should exist in System32 for SSL: SChannel.dll.

If you are able or want to use .NET, there is a much easier way to go with SslStream class.